# how to get average of rows that have a certain relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, average

I have a bunch of data that is stored pertaining to county demographics in a database. I need to be able to access the average of data within in the state of a certain county.
For example, I need to be able to get the average of all counties who's state_id matches the state_id of the county with a county_id of 1. Essentially, if a county was in Virginia, I would need the average of all of the counties in Virginia. I'm having trouble setting up this query, and I was hoping that you guys could give me some help. Here's what I have written, but it only returns one row from the database because of it linking the county_id of the two tables together.

```
SELECT AVG(demographic_data.percent_white) as avg_percent_white 
FROM demographic_data,counties, states 
WHERE counties.county_id = demographic_data.county_id AND counties.state_id = states.state_id
```

Here's my basic database layout:

```
counties
------------------------
county_id | county_name

states
---------------------
state_id | state_name

demographic_data
-----------------------------------------
percent_white | percent_black | county_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning one row, because there's an aggregate and no GROUP BY. If you want an average of all counties within a state, we'd expect only one row.

To get a "statewide" average, of all counties within a state, here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT AVG(d.percent_white) AS avg_percent_white
  FROM demographic_data d
  JOIN counties a
    ON a.county_id = d.county_id
  JOIN counties o
    ON o.state_id = a.state_id 
 WHERE o.county_id = 42
```

Note that there's no need to join to the `state` table. You just need all counties that have a matching state_id. The query above is using two references to the counties table. The reference aliased as "a" is for all the counties within a state, the reference aliased as "o" is to get the state_id for a particular county.

If you already had the state_id, you wouldn't need a second reference:

```
SELECT AVG(d.percent_white) AS avg_percent_white
  FROM demographic_data d
  JOIN counties a
    ON a.county_id = d.county_id
 WHERE a.state_id = 11
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q** What if I wanted to bring in another table.. Let's call it demographic_data_2 that was also linked via the county_id

**A** I made the assumption that the `demographic_data` table had one row per county_id. If the same holds true for the second table, then a simple JOIN operation.

```
  JOIN demographic_data_2 c
    ON c.county_id = d.county_id
```

With that table joined in, you could add an appropriate aggregate expression in the SELECT list (e.g. SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG).

The trouble spots are typically "missing" and "duplicate" data... when there isn't a row for every county_id in that second table, or there's more than one row for a particular county_id, that leads to rows not included in the aggregate, or getting double counted in the aggregate.

---

We note that the aggregate returned in the original query is an "average of averages". It's an average of the values for each county.

Consider:

```
bucket  count_red  count_blue  count_total  percent_red
------  ---------  ----------  -----------  -----------
     1        480           4         1000           48
     2         60           1          200           30
```

Note that there's a difference between an "average of averages", and calculating an average using totals.

```
SELECT AVG(percent_red) AS avg_percent_red
     , SUM(count_red)/SUM(count_total) AS tot_percent_red

avg_percent_red  tot_percent_red
---------------  ---------------
             39               45
```

Both values are valid, we just don't want to misinterpret or misrepresent either the value.

Comment: Great.. I have one last question.. What if I wanted to bring in another table.. Let's call it demographic_data_2 that was also linked via the county_id